# Timeouts in Selenium 3.3.1 used along side Firefox 52 with geckodriver v0.15

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using the new Selenium 3.3.1 Jar with Firefox 52. I require a timeout so I used the obvious one :-

```
Timeouts timeOuts = driver.manage().timeouts();
driver.navigate().to("http://www.google.com");
timeOuts.implicitlyWait(2000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.quit();
```

However everytime I get the following error :-

```
1489491244218   Marionette  WARN    Using deprecated data structure for setting timeouts
```

Is there any change in usage? Can Anyone point to the Recent Usage docs?

Comment: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/selenium-assistant/issues/27
This may help you.
Use  `v0.4.0-beta`

Comment: Can you point to what I am looking for? Because it suggests that the issue has been fixed but no change in the syntax as such!

Comment: Yes probably something regarding `Marionette` might have changed. Upgrading might resolve your problem.

Comment: I don't think I can upgrade anymore. I downloaded it this morning just 5-6 hours earlier.